# Fiddler (filtering to one device)

Tags: filter, fiddler

I've seen lots of the other answers here and there is one that I saw but I can't implement it. I can't really figure it out.

I'm trying to filter Fiddler so that there is only one device's traffic. I know I'm supposed to somehow use oSession["x-clientIP"], but I have no idea how. Is there anybody that could help me figure out what I have to paste in to the custom rules file? If lets say the client-ip that I was trying to filter based on was 192.200.1.1, how do I do this?

The documentation barely has anything for this (at least for what I looked for) and looking through the actual file doesn't have any examples I can work off of. Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 2):

Rules > Customize Rules. Scroll to **OnBeforeRequest**.

Add the following inside that block:

```
    if (!"192.200.1.1".Equals(oSession.oFlags["X-ClientIP"]))
    {
        oSession["ui-hide"] = "not the device I care about";
    }
```